# Parse RTF using Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtf

How do I parse RTF formatted text using Delphi? I need to parse RTF(the rtf contains text with many fonts)  to extract font name and plain text formatted with that font and put it in a list. I know that I can use Trichedit SelAttributes to achieve that, but using visual control makes it very slow for large text.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227899/using-trichedit-at-runtime-without-defining-a-parent).

Comment: It uses Trichedit. I want to avoid trichedit because using it to parse RTF is slow for large text

Comment: Parsing RTF is a complex and painfull task. Read the whole Q&A, especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229070/1431618. :-)

Comment: The RTF specification includes C example code for RTF parser (see http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec.html).

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it