# rtf and html can live in the same application?

Tags: html, delphi, storage, rtf

I have what I think it is a very popular problem. I have a legacy app that contains rtf fields. rtf in my case is used only for very basic features (font: size, style, color, ... hyperlinks). Anyway since I allow to paste from word sometimes some more complex things can go in there.

Now rtf is ok, even because with Report Builder I can get reports where rtf is printed.

The problem comes with web application. I am developing a web application that is basically an optional interface for my legacy application.

At this stage I solved the probelm by removing the rtf formatting (I use the TRichEdit trick discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214281/delphi-best-way-to-convert-rtf-to-text)).

Anyway ideally I would like to be able to see and edit formatted text in both the web application and the win32 application.

What can be the solution?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214281/delphi-best-way-to-convert-rtf-to-text) I found a link to the [ScroogeHTML](http://www.habarisoft.com/scroogexhtml.html) converter.

But even if I convert there are these points that i cannot reconcile:

1. Storage: what to store? Currently of course I store rtf.
2. Should I convert rtf to html every time I show the rich text in web app and then convert it back to rtf for storage?

Comment: It depends... If users are more reading than updating the data in your rtf, you can add another column with the html one...
Each time a user modify the RTF from the legacy app, you save the rtf and its html convertion to the new column...
Each time a user modify the HTML from the new app, you save the html and its RTF convertion to the current column...

Comment: THis is a solution, but an overhead. Expecially if I allow to add images in the future... Why HTML, may be version 6, doesn't contain also rtf spec?...

Comment: But where is the "trick"? All i see is `PlainText` employment which is pretty well-known... Also, HTML version 6, LOLWUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could implement a RTF editor in your web application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor

This way you don't have to change the storage format.